# Understanding 2 unit yield from 1lb ready to cook chicken

Tags: measurements

I have a recipe that calls for 2 unit (yield from 1lb ready to cook chicken) and it says it is 158 grams.

Can someone explain how this measurement works. How does 2 units from 1lb of chicken end up as 158 grams? Please explain it like I'm 5. :)

Comment: Could you please provide more context details and/or a link to the recipe?

Comment: The answer below is what I was looking for. I don't have an easy link to the recipe, sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's referring to the weight of each piece after cooking. 1 lb of uncooked chicken is 453.59 grams. Some use 450g as a quick rule as 4 grams is really not much in most applications. 450g divided by 2 would make each piece 225g raw. Cooked chicken generally loses 30% of its weight, so cooked is 70%, or .7 of the raw weight. 225g X .7 = 157.5g , which when rounded up is 158g.

Keep in mind this is the approximate cooked weight of each piece, your milage will vary depending on the quality of the chicken, whether white or dark meat, and how much fat is on it.